# UIGravityBehavior only rotate the view to follow gravity without falling

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

When adding a `UIDynamicItem` aka `UIView` to a `UIGravityBehavior` the object falls. I would like it to just rotate facing the earth without falling. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried also anchoring it with a `UIAttachmentBehavior` type `UIAttachmentBehaviorTypeAnchor`?

Comment: No I didn't try. I will try it now.